# D3 dynamic json key names

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

When you want to make a graph in d3 and you read your input from a json file (for example) the code goes pretty much like this :

```
 d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
});
```

In this particular example I got from d3noob.org, there is a json file with objects that have 2 keys (date and close). What if I don't know the key names of the json file and I have to use a string variable? For example :

```
d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, data) {
        var var1 = "date";
        var var2 = "close";
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.var1 = parseDate(d.var1);
            d.var2 = +d.var2;
        });
```

I tried doing that, but the console gives me an error

> d3.min.js:1 Error:  attribute d: Expected number,
>   "M0,NaNL106,NaNL212,…".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the bracket `[]` notation to access an object property whose name is stored in a variable.

eg: `d.var1 = parseDate(d.var1)` becomes `d[var1] = parseDate(d[var1])`.

Comment: thank your for the fast answer! it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, data) {
    var var1 = "date";
    var var2 = "close";
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d[var1] = parseDate(d[var1]);
        d[var2] = +d[var2];
    });
```